# Display data in next line in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have column field like `+`

```
 |d  | department | employee |
 |1  |  xxx       | abc,pqr  |
 |2  |  yyy       | xyz,yua  |
```

I want table should display data like `+`

```
 |d  | department | employee |
 |1  |  xxx       | abc,     |
 |   |            | pqr      |
 |2  |  yyy       | xyz,     |
 |   |            | yua      |
```

I am taking data in employee field using cross apply.

Comment: Why do you store the employees in a single column instead of in another table which is linked to this via foreign-key?

Comment: Is it an option to change the table structure? Because that `employee` field is a very bad design. Also, do you really want those empty cells and that comma after the employee names as seen in your output??

Answer (score 1):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM
(
SELECT 1 Id, 'xxx' department, 'abc,pqr' employee 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 'yyy' , 'xyz,yua' 
)TAB
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,department,LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'employee ' 
    FROM  
    (
         -- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' before '</M><M>' to your desired one
         SELECT ID,department,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(employee, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
         FROM #TEMP     
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT 
    -- Row number for each employee in a department
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 0))RNO,
    -- Find count of employee in that department 
    COUNT(employee) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)MAXX,*
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT 
CASE WHEN RNO <> 1 THEN NULL ELSE ID END ID,
CASE WHEN RNO <> 1 THEN NULL ELSE department END department,
-- Check if the employee is the last one in that department
CASE WHEN RNO = MAXX THEN employee ELSE employee+',' END employee
FROM CTE2
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc8ad/3) to view result

Comment: Did u get the result? @user3035655

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH your_table as
(
  SELECT 
    d,
    department,
    CAST ('<t>' + REPLACE(employee, ',', ',</t><t>') + 
      '</t>' AS XML) AS Col 
   FROM 
     (VALUES(1, 'xxx', 'abc,pqr'),(2 , 'yyy' , 'xyz,yua')) x(d, department, employee)
)
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY d ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) = 1 
  THEN d 
  ELSE NULL
  END as d,
  CASE WHEN 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY d ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) = 1 
  THEN department
  ELSE NULL
  END as department,
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') employee 
FROM your_table
CROSS APPLY Col.nodes ('/t') AS Split(a)
```

Result:

```
d     department  employee
1     xxx         abc,
NULL  NULL        pqr
2     yyy         xyz,
NULL  NULL        yua
```